# INSERT FROM 2 tables Copying all rows from 1 column from table 1 and only the last row from 1column on table 3

Tags: php, mysql, insert

as the title says, I want to Insert into table 3 (list_mail_usr) all the rows from a column on table 1 (temp_urs) and just the very last row from 1 column in table 2, you can see, all the rows from column 1 have the same ID which is the last row from the list_id column of the list_mail_nom table.

```
$tmp_usr = "INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (id_usuario,list_id)
SELECT temp_urs.id_usuario
JOIN list_mail_nom.list_id
WHERE MAX(ID) FROM list_mail_nom.list_id
";
```

This is what I have so far. And it's not working obviously ;(
Any suggestions?

This one almost works but insert each row from temp_usr 65 times

```
$tmp_usr = "INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (id_usuario,list_id)
            SELECT temp_usr.id_usuario,list_mail_nom.list_id
            FROM temp_usr,list_mail_nom";
$insert = $asies -> query($tmp_usr) or die (mysqli_error($asies));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using aggregate functions correctly.  To do what you're trying to do, you're going to need to GROUP BY and use a HAVING.  A much simpler query would be something like :

```
INSERT INTO new_table (new_a, new_b)
SELECT x.col, y.col
FROM x, y
WHERE y.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM y)
```

With large tables, MySQL's difficulties optimizing subqueries would become apparent.  If you can find the maximum ID separately & pass it in as a constant, performance will be much better against large tables (moreso large x than large y, since it's assumed that there's an index on your ID).

Comment: Oh my God... @Sean McSomthing. That was it, thank you, Thank You it works like a charm. Bless You

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell MySQL the VALUES are coming from your subquery:

```
$tmp_usr = "INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (id_usuario,list_id)
VALUES(
SELECT temp_urs.id_usuario, some_other_field_name
JOIN list_mail_nom.list_id
WHERE MAX(ID) FROM list_mail_nom.list_id)
";
```

Also, your select should output the same number of fields that you are inputting into list_mail_usr.  I represented the other field name in the above query with `some_other_field_name`

Comment: Thank's, and yes but, I only need the value from the last row from the list_id column of the list_mail_nom table, how can that fit into the "your select should output the same number of fields"? I have 35 rows in temp_urs and I need to be inserted like:
___________________________
|ID | id_usuario | list_id |
___________________________
|_1_|_juan choo__|__65_____|
|_1_|_mikel ram__|__65_____|
|_1_|_sam ramsan_|__65_____|

Comment: You show two column names (id_usuario and list_id).  If you only need one column, then you can eliminate the "some_other_field_name".  It should follow the format: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: The statment should look like: $tmp_usr="INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (ID, id_usuario, list_id) VALUES (SELECT list_mail_nom.ID, temp_urs.id_usuario, list_mail_nom.list_id FROM temp_urs.id JOIN list_mail_nom WHERE MAX(list_mail_nom.ID) from list_mail_nom.list_id)";

Comment: It's not working.... I'm trying but It's not working... In it should, there must be a different way cause this one's not working at all.. Any suggestion other than the approach I'm working whit? And the thing is that the list will be incrementing whit other list name id's so I don't think it's a good idea to copy the ID from the tem_usr list

Comment: This is working but, it returns 65 times each row from temp_usr

$tmp_usr = "INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (id_usuario,list_id) SELECT temp_usr.id_usuario,list_mail_nom.list_id FROM temp_usr,list_mail_nom";
$insert = $asies -> query($tmp_usr) or die (mysqli_error($asies));

Comment: Sorry, I missed copied.  I noticed that you removed the WHERE clause, but there is also a second FROM clause.  Try:  $tmp_usr="INSERT INTO list_mail_usr (ID, id_usuario, list_id) VALUES (SELECT list_mail_nom.ID, temp_urs.id_usuario, list_mail_nom.list_id FROM temp_urs.id JOIN list_mail_nom WHERE MAX(list_mail_nom.ID)";

Comment: Thanks man, I learned something from this. I'm grateful for your help.